# Azure XPlat Client - Add multiple domains at once

Tags: azure-xplat-cli

I am using the azure xplat client. I am migrating a site to azure, it has about 200 domains attached to it. Is there anyway to add multiple domains in one command?

I tried `azure site domain add domain1.com,domain2.com azuresitename` but that didn't work. I could run the script 200 times but I remember doing this via a command line before.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are working in ASM mode. The `azure site domain add` command supports only a single domain name. Your best option would be to feed your list into a script to automate running the command for each domain name.